# Discrete Windows phone slider

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to add steps in the windows phone 8 slider I want my slider to accept only values 0,1,2,3,4.

Also I want the template to be discrete showing a little thin line in each value on the slider just like ease of access in Windows phone 8 settings.

The sliders should be like 4 rectangular thin boxes on which if I slide get fill,

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make your own slider using scrollviewr other wise use telrik control

Comment: @MansinhDodiya I'm afraid but i didnt found in telrik regarding this, also in windows setting its already availabe, in ease of access, why cant i use the default one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reaching out to third party controls, you could try registering an attached property to do the mathematical rounding for you.  As a very quick and dirty example (that is probably way over the top for what needs to happen) you could create something like this.

```
public class SliderExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IntegerValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IntegerValue", typeof(int), typeof(SliderExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    public static void SetIntegerValue(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        ((Slider)element).ValueChanged += (s, e) => { ((Slider)s).Value = Math.Round(((Slider)s).Value); };
    }

    public static int GetIntegerValue(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)((Slider)element).Value;
    }
}
```

and then use it in your Slider as follows.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="sld" Minimum="0" Maximum="4" SmallChange="1" helper:SliderExtensions.IntegerValue="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=sld, Path=Value}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Don't forget to add the "helper" namespace to your XAML, and that this is largely untested other than a very quick look.

Comment: thanks... I have implemented this actually I am looking for something where the slider looks in break format, means all the values looks seperate bar in that. is anything possible via template

Answer (score 1):

using scroll viewer you can make slider or you can use telrik control.It gives good slider control, refer below link

[SlideView](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx)

[Slide Redcontrol for wp](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radanimations-features-animations-slide.html)

hope it will help you

Comment: Is there any way to download telerik.dll, i didnt find any link for the same

Comment: @Artist404: you have to istall this setup and copy paste dll from your C drive or installer path

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="TotalPlanedLeave" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Total Planed Leaves :"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="l1" Text="1" ></TextBlock>
</Grid>

<Slider Name="TotalPlanedLeaveS" ValueChanged="TotalPlanedLeaveS_ValueChanged" ></Slider>
```

in code behind

```
 private void TotalPlanedLeaveS_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            l1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TotalPlanedLeaveS.Value)).ToString();

        }
```